# Cancel Submit To Database In Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq

I want to ask about Linq. Can I discard change to database using Linq? For example, I've submit data to database, but I haven't use `db.SubmitChanges();` syntax. Well, this is going to be hard to explain, so let's take a look for the example.

```
//the Code for insert the data to database
db.myTable.InsertOnSubmit(insert);
```

So, if I want to submit to database, I have to use :

```
db.SubmitChanges();
```

But, what I want to do is to discard or cancel my insert data, so when I use `db.SubmitChanges();` the data will not go to the database.

I'm so sorry if this is so confusing, I'm still beginner.

Comment: If you omit `db.SubmitChanges()` It Wont be saved; create a new instance of yourcontext everything else is same as your db.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't call `SubmitChanges()` at the end and it won't save to DB.